# Edit option is not working in dynamic grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

```
 GridView gv = new GridView();

BoundField farmername = new BoundField();
farmername.HeaderText = "Farmer Name";
farmername.DataField = "farmername";
gv.Columns.Add(farmername);


BoundField villagename = new BoundField();
villagename.HeaderText = "Village Name";
villagename.DataField = "village";
gv.Columns.Add(villagename);

BoundField feedtype = new BoundField();
feedtype.HeaderText = "Feed Type";
feedtype.DataField = "feedtype";
gv.Columns.Add(feedtype);


BoundField bf50kg = new BoundField();
bf50kg.HeaderText = "50 Kg Bags";
bf50kg.DataField = "noof50kgsbags";
gv.Columns.Add(bf50kg);

CommandField cf = new CommandField();
cf.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
cf.ShowCancelButton = true;
cf.ShowEditButton = true;
gv.Columns.Add(cf);

gv.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(gv_RowEditing);
gv.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(gv_RowUpdating);
gv.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(gv_RowCancelingEdit);

gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
gv.ShowFooter = true;
gv.DataSource = dtIndentDetails;
gv.DataBind();
```

When I clicked on edit button its not spliting into update, Cancel buttons . How can I do this with command field .If I add gridview in aspx page, its splitting to  update and cancel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your command button with a link or an image button.An the put this one liner.

```
cf.CommandName = "Edit";
```

You can also do the same for cancel and update and pass in command names "cancel" and "update" respectively.This will be a work around.I also had trouble getting a dynamically generated command button to fire.

**UPDATE**

Another clean approach that will help.See attachment on drop box [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/Dynamically%20Templated%20GridView%20with%20Edit-Insert-Delete%20Options.zip)

Comment: Can u place your code. I have a problem When I clicked the edit button. The bound fields are not converted into textboxes  to edit

Comment: I have updated my answer with an attachment.You now have to change your bound fields to normal text boxes.

Comment: I checked your look previously but the fields are not converting to Textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Assign command Name and in Event handler use code like this for editing and updating. I have used vb.net.

```
Create: Link Button b= new Link Button()
cf.ShowEditButton = true;
cf.CommandName="Edit";
gv.Columns.Add(cf);
```

Use Item Templates and Edit Templates.When edit command fire automatically rowediting method will be executed.

```
Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs)       Handles grdCustomers.RowEditing
grdCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
GetAllCustomersData()
End Sub
```

For Updating:

```
Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
Dim result As Boolean
Dim CustObj As New Services.Entities.Customers.Customer
CustObj.CustomerID = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblCustomerId"), Label).Text
CustObj.ContactName = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtContactName"), TextBox).Text
CustObj.City = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlCity1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString

'Type of binding
Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding

'Endpoint name defining
Dim myEndPoint As New   EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CustomerServiceUrl").ToString())

Dim myChannelFactory As ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer) = New ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer)(myBinding, myEndPoint)

'Creating a Channel to access Services
Dim client As ICustomer = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel

result = client.UpdateCustomerDetails(CustObj)

grdCustomers.EditIndex = -1
GetAllCustomersData()
Sub End
```

For Canceling Update:

```
Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
grdCustomers.EditIndex = -1
GetAllCustomersData()
End Sub
```

Comment: How to convert my bound fields to textboxes

Comment: Place Textboxes in edit template and manipulate. When ever you click on edit link button automatically it will display text boxes in the place of bounded data

Comment: I am new to this can you place some code. I may helps better.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to work out in this way. i have made an example.

will display you the edit command button do it from back end.

This is my grid:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="grdCustomers" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" AllowSorting="true"
                     OnRowEditing="grdCustomers_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="grdCustomers_RowDeleting" HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green"
                     OnRowUpdating="grdCustomers_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdCustomers_RowCancelingEdit"  AllowPaging="false"  ShowFooter="true" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Id">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>' HeaderText=""  runat="server" ID="lblcustomerId"   />
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>


                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("ContactName")%>' ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactName" runat="server" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Label id="lblCity" Text='<%#Eval("City")%>' runat="server" /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity1" runat="server" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Edit"  />


                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

My Back End Code to bind data:

```
Protected Sub GetAllCustomersData()
    ' List to Hold the results

    'Type of binding
    Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding

    'Endpoint name defining
    Dim myEndPoint As New EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CustomerServiceUrl").ToString())

    'Registering Service Reference
    Dim MychannelFactory As ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer) = New ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer)(myBinding, myEndPoint)

    'Creating a Channel to access Services
    Dim client As ICustomer = MychannelFactory.CreateChannel

    lst = client.GetCustomerData()
    grdCustomers.DataSource = lst
    grdCustomers.DataBind()
End Sub
```

For Row Editing:

```
Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles grdCustomers.RowEditing
    grdCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    GetAllCustomersData()

End Sub
```

For Row Updating:

Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim CustObj As New Services.Entities.Customers.Customer
        CustObj.CustomerID = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblCustomerId"), Label).Text
        CustObj.ContactName = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtContactName"), TextBox).Text
        CustObj.City = DirectCast(grdCustomers.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlCity1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue.ToString

```
    'Type of binding
    Dim myBinding As New BasicHttpBinding

    'Endpoint name defining
    Dim myEndPoint As New EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CustomerServiceUrl").ToString())

    Dim myChannelFactory As ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer) = New ChannelFactory(Of ICustomer)(myBinding, myEndPoint)
    'Creating a Channel to access Services
    Dim client As ICustomer = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel
    result = client.UpdateCustomerDetails(CustObj)
    grdCustomers.EditIndex = -1
    GetAllCustomersData()
End Sub
```

For Row Edit Cancel Button:

```
  Protected Sub grdCustomers_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    grdCustomers.EditIndex = -1
    GetAllCustomersData()
  End Sub
```

Comment: OK Thanks for your code.but I need the same code in programatically(CS Page).